# Unlimited data plan to use In the whole of Europe for YouTube streaming

Tags: europe, data-plans, mobile-operators

I'm planning a Europe-wide trip in a motorhome I've bought. I'd like to stream the trip from the front of the motorhome to YouTube, basically a live landscape with music. To do this I'm trying to overcome the technical hurdle of data usage throughout Europe.

At the moment, my super basic plan is to use a phone to stream from with a high-quality video image and buy individual pre-paid unlimited SIM cards in each country as I arrive (I'm currently with Three in England and they allow unlimited data within England, but only 12 GB per month tethered or roaming in Europe).

However my preferred option would to be use a Mobile Wifi (MiFi) dongle as then I can use a proper webcam/streaming camera connected to a desktop or laptop in the camper. I can't find an unlimited Europe-wide MiFi plan in the UK, but that doesn't mean a different country in Europe doesn't have a viable plan.

Does anyone know of which countries might have viable data plans?

Comment: Good luck with it!

Comment: never even consider coming to switzerland with that idea =) Roaming here is horrible

Comment: `only 12 GB per month`... kids these days...

Comment: Other problems someone else should elaborate on: maximum youtube video length is 10 hours. You would have to start several videos. Also, the idea to have mobile data coverage everywhere is rather odd. This isn't even the case in England, I suggest you record the whole trip and then later upload it on wifi.

Comment: @Sebastian: Live streaming has no maximum length precisely because it's live.

Comment: @SJuan76 haha, I'm almost 30! 12GB per month can be burnt through when tethering pretty easily; netflix, youtube, torrenting, application updates, downloading games, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to only consider two options: Use local pay-as-you-go SIMs with a cell phone or a mobile wi-fi router with one subscription while roaming. There is however no reason why you shouldn't be able to use a wi-fi router with different local subscriptions.

I know that it is risky to claim that something is not going to work, but there are several reasons why you won't (cheaply) be able to do what you are planning:

- Pay-as-you-go subscriptions are in many European countries limitied to relatively small data packages.
- Within the EEA, roaming surcharges have been prohibited since last summer, but there are exceptions. The whole-sale tariffs for data usage (what the network operators charge each other for their subscriber's data usage while roaming) are still quite steep. Therefore most (if not all) subscriptions with unlimited domestic data plans have some kind of limit or restrictions to roaming usage.
- In many European countries, cellular coverage or network capacity is so poor, that you are not likely to reliably stream high quality video in most locations.

Comment: Plus usually if you have a 4G/LTE plan in the UK you only seem to connect to a slow 3G in Europe, you can tell the local networks are (rightly) putting their native paying customers first.

Comment: @BritishSam Bandwidth throttling is usually imposed by your own provider and not the hosting provider. Unless a cell is seriously congested and a provider therefore chooses to prioritize traffic from its own customers, it would make no sense to throttle traffic from roaming devices as the revenue is usually quite a bit higher than for 'native' traffic.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I'm not sure what you mean by a wi-fi router with different local subscriptions? As far as I know that's what mobile wi-fi routers are capable of doing.

Comment: @MaxPowah I understood your question as if you believe that a mobile wi-fi router can only be used with a single subscription and that you therefore need *one* subscription offering enough data usage in all of Europe.

Comment: Carrier "three" which is uk based provides unlimited data at lte speeds but only in uk that's because there is a EU wide limitation of 15 gb however they have have a 12 pound add on that gives you 12gb of data eu wide .. the app is horrible though and works only within the uk (or if you have a uk vpn connection set up on your phone e.g using a vpn app which usually needs subscription to the company that owns said app) lebara germany also has relative cheap addons for data that work eu wide the minus side is that they provide only 3g speeds the plus side is that they give unlimited or a few hun